# Converting arrayfire array to a numpy array using pybind

Tags: c++, pybind11

I am a complete novice trying to interface some code I wrote with python with another code written with C++. The basic gist is that I have a function in my python code that takes in three numpy arrays, does some processing with them, and then spits out another numpy array. The C++ code I am trying to hook it up to will produce three arrayfire arrays that should be converted to numpy arrays fed into my python script for processing, and then I want my python script to do the processing on these arrays and spit out the resulting array which should then be converted back into an arrayfire array. I really have very little knowledge of C++ or pybind, so I've basically been working off trial/error combined with chatGPT. Unfortunately, I've hit a complete wall in the conversion step (converting to and from arrayfire arrays to numpy arrays). I'm trying to do the most simple "Hello world" example I can think of (i.e. convert a 2 by 2 arrayfire array to numpy), but when I compile and run this code, I inevitably end with a segmentation fault. I'm a bit at my wits end here, so I'm trying to figure out what is going wrong.

Here is my c++ code so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <arrayfire.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

int main() {
    af::array arr = af::array({2, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4}).as(af::dtype::f32);

    // Get the data as a pointer
    float *h_arr = arr.host<float>();

    // Convert the C++ array to a NumPy array
    py::array np_arr = py::array(
        py::buffer_info(
            h_arr,
            sizeof(float),
            py::format_descriptor<float>::format(),
            2,
            {2, 2},
            {sizeof(float) * 2, sizeof(float)}
        )
    );

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles fine, but when I run it I inevitably get a segmentation fault, and being a novice, it's very hard to figure out what is the cause of this.

Comment: Try to run it in a debugger (like gdb or lldb) and see where it crashes. Compile with `-g` for better debugging support

Comment: Thanks unddoch! I should provide an update in case anyone comes across this issue in the future: the problem was that I didn't start the python interpreter at the beginning of main through the statement py::scoped_interpreter guard{} . This resolves the issue.